# The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance

Tags: partitioning

Im trying to parition but get the following error -

```
The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.

(parted) print
Model: Seagate BUP Slim Mac SL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags

(parted) mkpart                                                           
Partition name?  []? part1
File system type?  [ext2]? ext4                                           
Start? 10                                                                 
End? 100                                                                  
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the output of a `unit s print` command *after* the creation of the partition, I can't be sure of what's going on here. I just tried this on a USB flash drive and got no such warning; but that drive also reports a physical sector size of 512 bytes, not the 4096 bytes of your disk. Also, you don't say what version of Ubuntu or `parted` you're using (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and `parted` 3.2-15).

In any event, my `unit s print` output is:

```
Number  Start   End      Size     File system  Name   Flags
 1      20480s  194559s  174080s               part1
```

This is properly aligned on most disks.

To back up, there are several reasons why partitions should be "aligned" -- that is, created on multiples of certain sector numbers. Reasons include:

- Many modern hard disks use 4096-byte physical sectors; but to improve compatibility, they divide each of these into eight 512-byte logical sectors. The trouble is that, if you were to write to fewer than all eight of those logical sectors, the disk would have to read the full physical sector, modify it, and write the result back to the disk. This would take more time than writing the full physical sector (that is, all eight of its logical sectors). Because many filesystems use data structures that are 4096 bytes or larger, starting a filesystem (partition) on something other than an eight-sector boundary can cause severe performance degradation. See [this article I wrote for IBM developerWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-on-4kb-sector-disks/) for more on this subject, including benchmark tests showing the amount of degradation that can result. (A caveat: I did those tests several years ago. The results might be different now because of changes in hardware or software.)
- In some types of RAID configuration, data is "striped" across multiple disks. This can result in performance improvements, but those improvements are best if partitions are laid out with starting points in multiples of the stripe size, which is typically in the 16 KiB to 256 KiB size range.
- SSDs can see performance and longevity effects based on their erase block size, which is typically 512 KiB to 1 MiB, although I've heard of SSDs with peculiar erase block sizes, such as 3 MiB.

In most cases, alignment on 2048-sector (1 MiB) boundaries works well for all these technologies. (An SSD with a 3 MiB erase block size would be an exception to this rule.) This value has become the default for most partitioning tools. Depending on how `parted` interpreted your input (units, etc.) and how it's determining whether your partitions are optimally aligned, you might or might have a real problem. That's why I said you need to look at the `unit s print` output. (The `unit s` part is critical; without that part, `parted` will show you partition start and end points rounded to MiB, GiB, or some other value, which is not precise enough for determining proper alignment.)

There are cases in which `parted` is known to complain without cause. For instance, it's impossible to properly align extended partitions on MBR disks, since these partitions' only real data structures are 512 bytes in size; but `parted` (or some versions of it, anyhow) will complain if an extended partition doesn't start on an alignment boundary. IIRC, some versions also look at the *end point* of the partition, but that's not relevant, except insofar as it can affect the next partition's start point.

One final point: In my test, `parted` treated a start point of `10` as 10 MiB -- or more likely, as 10 MB, and then rounded for proper alignment. It then seems to have treated the `100` end point as 100 MB, and again rounded it for alignment. In any event, a 10 MiB (the result after rounding) start point leaves close to 10 MiB of unused space at the start of the disk. Even with 1 MiB alignment, that's 9 MiB of unused space. This isn't a large amount of space on a modern disk, but you might want to reconsider and start the first partition at 1 MiB.

Answer (score 1):

parted will calculate proper alignment if you use percentages instead of sectors:

```
(parted) mkpart
Partition name?  []? part1
File system type?  [ext2]? ext4
Start? 0%
End? 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Backup the data from the misaligned partition, delete and recreate the partition using `gparted`, making sure that the following is set as shown...

[image]

Restore your data when complete.